# Actions you can perform while swimming

Tags: battlefield-4

I know you can do these while swimming:

1. Use your sidearm
2. Place M2 SLAM
3. Place C4

What other actions can one perform while swimming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, in addition to the ones you've mentioned already:

- Use your sidearm
- Place M2 SLAM
- Place C4

You can also

- Knife enemies
- Dive (by pressing crouch)
- Use the repair tool
- Enter vehicles

Comment: Don't forget using the repair tool.

Comment: @Lyrion Right, thanks. I knew I forgot something ;) Edited.

Comment: Also might sound a bit obvious, but you can get into vehicles from the water. A useful tip is to hold E and you'll jump into the vehicle as soon as it comes in range, rather than spamming E. Very useful if you're the bomb carrier in obliteration and someone is coming to pick you up in a chopper.

Comment: @tombull89 Also true. It's kinda obvious, but I'll add it to the list. And the thing with holding E is very useful, also on land. Prevents you from accidentally getting out of the chopper that just picked you up.

Comment: Good answer, waiting for more actions if there are any.